# Adjust my Tikz in final page

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I write a lot in my TikZ, the words leave the page. I want to fix it.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=west] (c1) {\textbf{one}};
\node [below right = of  c1.south west] (c11) {If  c=1  $\rightarrow$ hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello     hello hello hello hello hello hello hello};
\node [below=of c11.west,anchor=west] (c12) {If c=0  $\rightarrow$ Aun no han pasado 10 segundos};

\foreach \value in {1,2}
\draw[->] (c1.south west) |- (c1\value.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Also if is possible, I want this result with other mofications:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: I can't really get what do you mean by "more short" and "center", as for the line break in TikZ, as far as I can tell, there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No automatic line breaking is done in nodes by default, to have that you need to add a `text width` to the node options. However, that doesn't work so well with the alignment relative to the arrow. A nice way of doing this is to use a `\matrix`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (m) [
   matrix of nodes,
   column 2/.style={text width=8cm}, % width of second column, activates automatic lie breaking
   nodes={anchor=base} 
   ]
 {
  If $c=1 \rightarrow$ & hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
                  hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello \\
 If $c=0 \rightarrow$ & Aun no han pasado 10 segundos \\
};

\node (one) [
   above left=1cm and 0.3cm of m, % position relative to the matrix
   font=\bfseries, % bold font
   outer ysep=5pt % lines drawn to the node will stop at this distance from the noce
]  {one};

\draw [<-] (m-2-1) -| (one);
\draw [<-] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-1 -| one);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Old answer

One workaround is to place the long text in second node, see second example below. There are likely more elegant ways of doing that, but it's the first thing that came to mind.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=west] (c1) {\textbf{one}};
\node [below right = of  c1.south west,text width=8cm] (c11) {If  $c=1  \rightarrow$ hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello     hello hello hello hello hello hello hello};
\node [below=of c11.west,anchor=west] (c12) {If $c=0  \rightarrow$ Aun no han pasado 10 segundos};

\foreach \value in {1,2}
\draw[->] (c1.south) |- (c1\value.west);

\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=west] (c1) {\textbf{one}};
\node [below right=of  c1.south west] (c11) {If  $c=1  \rightarrow$};
\node [right=0pt    of c11.base east,anchor=base west,text width=8cm,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] {hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
                  hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello};
\node [below=2cm of c11.west,anchor=west] (c12) {If $c=0  \rightarrow$ Aun no han pasado 10 segundos};

\foreach \value in {1,2}
\draw[->] (c1.south) |- (c1\value.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but I put `c=N` inside math mode as well, seems like it belongs there.

Comment: Do you know how separate the text If c=1... of if=0.. ?

Comment: @Solid I updated my answer. Do you mean to increase the vertical separation between the two points? If so, see the second example, i.e. `below=2cm of c11.west`. Also, to center "one" above the line, draw the line from the `south` anchor, not `south west`.

Comment: @Solid So, was that sufficient, or is there anything else missing? Remember to upvote useful answers.

Comment: Just arrive to my house , sorry. Its perfect!!Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: @Solid No worries. Sorry, didn't mean to be pushy.